# I'm trying to mount Ubuntu to a dvd and make it bootable. I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Tags: 12.04

can anyone help me? I'm trying to use Ubuntu to mod windows 7 to bypass a forgotten password.

Comment: Have you downloaded the iso file from Ubuntu.com? Have you [checked for corrupted download using mdsum?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) Have you burned the iso into the DVD [using the special software?](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) Unless you tell us what you have done, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean by "mounting" just simply burning it to a DVD and using the Live-Feature:
Depending on the operating system you are using now just download a DVD burning application *(a)* and download the ISO-image from the official [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/).

Then burn this image using the "burn image to disc"-feature without extracting the files from the ISO file to your harddisk. (Some users of tools like WinRAR get confused because WinRAR recognizes ISO-Files as archive files.) So, just select the ISO file using your burning application and create a DVD file.

Then insert this Disc into your computer and try to reboot. In many cases the computer would automatically boot from the inserted disc. Otherwise you should see your BIOS (normally you can enter BIOS by pressing  or  or some other F-Key during the boot sequence) and set there the boot sequency to first boot from Disc-/DVD-Drives.

(a) some tools for Windows to burn DVDs would be DiscBurner XP or ImageBurn. For Ubuntu there's available Brasero, K3b and many more.